# Named parameter does not follow java identifier rules in MySQL/SQL/JPQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I would like to create a JPQL query that **shows the list of users in the same group as the logged in user**.

Indeed, that's what I already did

```
public List<Utilisateur> getListUser(Long id) {
    return getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.group.id =:" +id)
            .getResultList();
}
```

and my User tables is as follows

User: id, name, tel, email, group, ...

Group: id, name, type.

My method to retrieve the group of the current user

```
public Long currentIdGroup() {
    Utilisateur usere = EntityRealm.getUser();
    if (usere == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return EntityRealm.getUser().getGroup().getId();
}
```

The declaration of the list in the Bean.

```
public List<Utilisateur> getListusersGroup() {
    return this.utilisateurService.getListUser(currentIdGroup());

}
```

But, I'm getting this error in glassfish

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.group.id =:1]. [51, 53] The named input parameter ''{0}'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.
```

Thank you in advance for your crucial help.

Many things to you.

Comment: Remove the colon

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the colon:

`.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.group.id =" +id)`

Ideally you should use:

`.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.group.id =:param")`

and then:

`.setParameter("param", id);`

to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: in fact I forgot to say that group is a foreign key. Like this  User: id, name, tel, email, FK group_id, ...

Group: id, name, type. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks egallardo for your help. It's work. Many thanks.